# Evento onmousemove com jquery

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Estou tentando recriar este tooltip http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/ com jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tooltip").mousemove(function(event) {
    $(".text").style.top = (event.pageY + 20) + "px";
    $(".text").style.left = (event.pageX + 20) + "px";
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip span {
  display:none;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="text">Texto</span>
  <p>Passe o mouse aqui.</p>
</div>
```

Porém, o Texto não acompanha o movimento do mouse. Alguém poderia me dizer como fazer isso?

Comment: O jQuery esta retornando todos os elementos encontrados, logo é um objeto, altere `$(".text").style` para `$(".text")[0].style`, caso você tiver mais de um elemento você terá que percorrer esse objeto.

Comment: Veja funcionando em [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/870828/)

Comment: É isso mesmo! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @NoobSaibot Coloque como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como [citado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334939/evento-onmousemove-com-jquery/334963#comment677342_334959) pelo Anderson, seria necessário uma resposta que seja flexível ao número de `tooltips` que tiver na página.

Com base nesse [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/), criei esse exemplo que irá aplicar o efeito a todos os `tooltips` presente no documento.

Como estás a usar `jquery`, me senti livre em usar o método `css()` para realizar as alterações.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tooltip').each(function(){
    $(this).mousemove(function(ev){
      var x = ev.clientX,
          y = ev.clientY
      $(".text", this).css("top", (y + 20) + "px"); 
      $(".text", this).css("left", (x + 20) + "px") ;
    })
  }); 
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip span {
  display:none;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="text">Texto</span>
  <p>Passe o mouse aqui.</p>
</div>

<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="text">Outro texto</span>
  <p>Outro tooltip</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você esta tentando achar um elemento pela classe indique que você quer o primeiro elemento encontrado no caso [0] a primeira posição.

De uma olhada no exemplo que fiz embaixo, espero ter ajudado...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tooltip").mousemove(function(event) {
    $(".text")[0].style.top = (event.pageY + 20) + "px";
    $(".text")[0].style.left = (event.pageX + 20) + "px";
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip span {
  display:none;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="text">Texto</span>
  <p>Passe o mouse aqui.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: E se houverem vários tooltips na página, como ficaria?

Comment: Se houvesse muitos tooltips seria melhor fazer uma seleção por ID, ao meu ver, porém pode ter alguma forma mais fácil de criar vários ID's diferentes e selecionar um por um, vou dar uma pesquisada e tente te informar melhor...

Comment: Você já está selecionando pelo elemento em `.tooltip` no evento, então basta buscar pelo `.text` dentro dele. `$(this).children('.text').style.top`, por exemplo.

Comment: Ah certo Obrigado... é que também estou correndo atras dos estudos com jQuery tem muitos macetes e coisas que ainda não sei e tenho duvida, mas obrigado.

Comment: Faça o teste e adicione na sua resposta :D